# Split Strings using a URL as delimiter in Robot

Tags: string, split, robotframework

I am trying to split a string that is a long URL, when I try to use Split String in Robot where the delimiter is something like 'www.google.com' I am continually getting errors about "Need more values than 1"

Can I use a delimiter with .'s in it?  It seems like I can't, but I don't see why it would matter if the delimiter is used as a string.  I am doing a couple of Split Strings in a row, and this works in cases where the domain is localhost, just not with a server name/domain.

The way I am structuring my case is as:

```
${link01}   ${link02} =  Split String 'http://www.google.com/myurl/answer'  'www.google.com'
```

I would expect the following:

```
${link01} = 'http://'
${link02} = '/myurl/answer'
```

Instead I get:
Cannot assign return values: Need more values than 1

Can I use Split String this way or do I need to use a regex?

--EDIT--
Adding my Robot Keyword.

I send in a list of multiple links from a JSON Response, I only want to access one of these which has a form like http://www.google.com/myurl/answer-{GUI} and I only want to have myurl/answer-{GUI} in ${l_page_link}.

Adding the arguments so my search term is www.google.com I find that it returns *"Need more values than 1"* but if I use google.com it does this correctly.

```
[Arguments]  ${a_pagination_list} | ${a_pagination_placement} | ${a_search_term}=localhost/
${l_link}   ${l_indexer}=   Split String    ${a_pagination_list[${a_pagination_placement}]} >;
${l_base}   ${l_page_link}= Split String    ${l_link}   ${a_search_term}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below one:

```
@{link} =    Split String    http://www.google.com/myurl/answer    www.google.com
```

Split words will be returned as a list.

Comment: It works as long as I have the values written out, sadly it doesn't work when I put them in variables.  You gave me something to check on though, and that's good.  Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelF, Replacing values with variables doesn't have impact. I have tested and it works fine. Can u share the script and error message.?

Comment: I did find it worked if I kept at it, but consistently when running the Robot Keyword www.google.com did not match, but gave me "Need more values than 1".  If I use google.com that works consistently.  I wasn't sure if the structure had something to do with it, but its a string so I think not.  Just weird...for now I am using the google.com form to match and split.  I'd be curious why www.google.com did not match consistenly.  Unless its to do with the 2.8.7 version I need to use